# There is an error called 'list object is not callable' . Tried this in python 3.7.3.Could you pls help me with this

Tags: list, methods

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfdza.png)
 this is my code

Comment: Please include your code in the question here and if possible try to elaborate more on this..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure It's working for me

```py
my_dictionary={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}
my_dictionary
n=list(my_dictionary)
print(n)

['key1', 'key2']
```